# cypress - how to get classes of element

Tags: typescript, cypress

I want to return class names of DOM element as string or (preferable) array of strings.

`cy.get(selector).?`

I don't want to use

`cy.get(selector).should('have.class', 'abc')`

as I need to use the class name further in the test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll use the `.invoke()` to call the `.attr()` to get the `classList` of the jquery element.

```html
// html
<ul class="class1 class2 class3"> List
</ul>
```

```js
cy.get(selector)
  .invoke('attr', 'class') // returns "class1 class2 class3"
  .then(classList => classList.split(' ')) // converts to array of strings
```